# routing specific IP address trough a sock5 server

Tags: networking, mac, routing, socks5

I am already on a vpn. I want to connect to one website(123.456.789.10) which only works if I connect it to through sock5 server ( 123.777.888.192:1080).
I can do this by using proxifier app, but now this app is not allowed to be installed. So, it will be very helpful if anyone can guide how can I setup my system to route only one ip through the socks5 server.

P.N. website(123.456.789.10) will work only when my vpn is connected.

I tried using TS-wrap but it didn't work.
I tried to understand how to use tun2socks but wasn't able to understand the document. It's too high level for beginners like me.

Any help will be appreciated.

P.N. I am looking for setup help on Mac.

Comment: As an alternative, maybe you can find a browser that lets you route all traffic through the SOCKS5, and use that browser for this website only. On Windows this can be done in Firefox, so using Chrome/Edge/Safari for regular websites and Firefox only for this website

Comment: Thanks, but need one application also to connect through socks5 server. So, only using the browser will not work..